# why https can protect username and password?

Tags: oauth, https

I am wondering why https can protect username and password.
I have already read specification about oauth1.0 and part of oauth2.0.
In oauth2.0, we use https to pass key and secret.
As i know https is safe to transmit username and password.
But I think i can still do replay accacks.
In many websites, system just pass key and secret to authenticate user, but aftering learning oauth1.0, I think it is not secure.Now I am confused if i need a signature like oauth1.0 whenever authenticate user by http.